# Android NoClassDefFoundError - for a class that is in an included aar module

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, aar

I created a aar file using "Build APK" and included it as a module in my project. Also added the module dependency. It compiles fine but when I run the app, it throws a ClassDefNotFoundError for a class from that included module. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Not sure what part of code to post here, if you let me know, I will post that part as well.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have a targetApi() annotation in the class? If so, when you run the app on an API below the value specified, the class won't be included. I had that problem before.

Comment: Target is 25 on both

Comment: What do you mean on both? What is the API level of the device you're running the code on?

Comment: The device API is 23. I have been running this app on that device without any issue. The aar module inclusion is what is causing the app to crash now. The target API in app and aar module is 25.

Comment: The problem is you are attempting to access code that requires a higher API level than the device currently supports and the class or classes are included in the final apk that gets loaded to the phone. You need to wrap access to the code in a conditional that checks the API level of the current device at Runtime and do something else when the API is below 25.

Comment: I am not sure about that because the minSdkVersion is 16, I have the min and target same in app and the aar module and the app has been running fine on this device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159953/discussion-between-krishnan-v-s-and-wade-wilson).

Comment: Can you add the code for dependency mentioned in build.gradle for that aar?